# Flutter run not working on android emulator using vs code

Tags: flutter, android-emulator

I am trying to learn flutter and I have set up flutter, vs code and android studio. My project runs fine on web and window devices but I can't run the app on android emulator.

When I run the app on android emulator I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Tandin\Desktop\app2\hellow> flutter run
Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone64 x86 64. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
e: C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle.kts:1:1: Cannot access implicit script receiver class 'org.gradle.api.Project'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
e: C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle.kts:5:1: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
public open fun apply(p0: Closure<(raw) Any!>): Unit defined in Flutter_gradle
public open fun apply(p0: (Mutable)Map<String!, *>): Unit defined in Flutter_gradle
public open fun apply(p0: Action<in ObjectConfigurationAction!>): Unit defined in Flutter_gradle
e: C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle.kts:7:26: Unresolved reference: Plugin
e: C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle.kts:7:33: Unresolved reference: Project
e: C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle.kts:8:5: 'apply' overrides nothing
e: C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle.kts:8:33: Unresolved reference: Project
e: C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle.kts:11:13: Unresolved reference: getProperty
e: C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle.kts:12:17: Unresolved reference: getProperty
e: C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle.kts:15:25: Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public inline fun <reified T> ObjectFactory.setProperty(): SetProperty<TypeVariable(T)> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
public inline fun <T : Any> ObjectFactory.setProperty(elementType: KClass<TypeVariable(T)>): SetProperty<TypeVariable(T)> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
e: C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle.kts:16:25: Unresolved reference: getProperty
e: C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle.kts:17:29: Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public inline fun <reified T> ObjectFactory.setProperty(): SetProperty<TypeVariable(T)> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
public inline fun <T : Any> ObjectFactory.setProperty(elementType: KClass<TypeVariable(T)>): SetProperty<TypeVariable(T)> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
e: C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle.kts:25:25: Unresolved reference: getProperty
e: C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle.kts:26:29: Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public inline fun <reified T> ObjectFactory.setProperty(): SetProperty<TypeVariable(T)> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
public inline fun <T : Any> ObjectFactory.setProperty(elementType: KClass<TypeVariable(T)>): SetProperty<TypeVariable(T)> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
e: Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
    class org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.support.CompiledKotlinBuildScript, unresolved supertypes: org.gradle.api.plugins.PluginAware
    class org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.support.DefaultKotlinScript, unresolved supertypes: org.gradle.internal.scripts.GradleScript
Adding -Xextended-compiler-checks argument might provide additional information.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle.kts' line: 1

* What went wrong:
Script compilation errors:

  Line 01:
           ^ Cannot access implicit script receiver class 'org.gradle.api.Project'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

  Line 05: apply<FlutterPluginKts>()
           ^ None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
               public open fun apply(p0: Closure<(raw) Any!>): Unit defined in Flutter_gradle
               public open fun apply(p0: (Mutable)Map<String!, *>): Unit defined in Flutter_gradle
               public open fun apply(p0: Action<in ObjectConfigurationAction!>): Unit defined in Flutter_gradle

  Line 07: class FlutterPluginKts : Plugin<Project> {
                                    ^ Unresolved reference: Plugin

  Line 07: class FlutterPluginKts : Plugin<Project> {
                                           ^ Unresolved reference: Project

  Line 08:     override fun apply(project: Project) {
               ^ 'apply' overrides nothing

  Line 08:     override fun apply(project: Project) {
                                           ^ Unresolved reference: Project

  Line 11:             getProperty("android").withGroovyBuilder {
                       ^ Unresolved reference: getProperty

  Line 12:                 getProperty("defaultConfig").withGroovyBuilder {
                           ^ Unresolved reference: getProperty

  Line 15:                         setProperty("multiDexEnabled", true)
                                   ^ Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
                                       public inline fun <reified T> ObjectFactory.setProperty(): SetProperty<TypeVariable(T)> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl      
                                       public inline fun <T : Any> ObjectFactory.setProperty(elementType: KClass<TypeVariable(T)>): SetProperty<TypeVariable(T)> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl

  Line 16:                         getProperty("manifestPlaceholders").withGroovyBuilder {
                                   ^ Unresolved reference: getProperty

  Line 17:                             setProperty("applicationName", "io.flutter.app.FlutterMultiDexApplication")
                                       ^ Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
                                           public inline fun <reified T> ObjectFactory.setProperty(): SetProperty<TypeVariable(T)> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl  
                                           public inline fun <T : Any> ObjectFactory.setProperty(elementType: KClass<TypeVariable(T)>): SetProperty<TypeVariable(T)> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl

  Line 25:                         getProperty("manifestPlaceholders").withGroovyBuilder {
                                   ^ Unresolved reference: getProperty

  Line 26:                             setProperty("applicationName", baseApplicationName)
                                       ^ Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
                                           public inline fun <reified T> ObjectFactory.setProperty(): SetProperty<TypeVariable(T)> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl  
                                           public inline fun <T : Any> ObjectFactory.setProperty(elementType: KClass<TypeVariable(T)>): SetProperty<TypeVariable(T)> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl

  Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
      class org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.support.CompiledKotlinBuildScript, unresolved supertypes: org.gradle.api.plugins.PluginAware
      class org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.support.DefaultKotlinScript, unresolved supertypes: org.gradle.internal.scripts.GradleScript
  Adding -Xextended-compiler-checks argument might provide additional information.


14 errors

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             11.3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I tried with default project and haven't made any changes. Anyone know what I am doing wrong? Please help

Comment: Are you sure that you've created a project, not a plugin?

Comment: No. It's the default flutter project I am having trouble running on android emulator.I get gradle error above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that there is a problem with the Gradle configuration of your Flutter project.

Try the following:

1. Update Gradle wrapper `flutter upgrade --force`
2. Clear cache: `flutter clean`
3. Disable Gradle service: Go to Preferences --> Settings and search after Flutter --> Run: Enable Gradle 'offline mode'" and disable the option.

Alternatively, you can also try to reinstall the Flutter SDK

Comment: I couldn't find the setting to disable gradle service using vs code.can you please repeat the process and what will happen if I disable gradle service?

Comment: Click on the "Extensions" icon in the Activity Bar on the side (or press Ctrl+Shift+X or Cmd+Shift+X on macOS). In the Extensions view, search for "Gradle" or "Java Language Support" in the search bar.
Locate the extension that provides the Gradle service (e.g., "Language Support for Java" or "Gradle Language Support") and click on it. You will see an option to "Uninstall" or "Disable" the extension. Click on the appropriate button to remove or disable the extension.

It will deactivates Gradle-specific functionalities that are potentially responsible for the error 

I hope it will help

Comment: Flutter upgrade solved the issue.Maybe it was the gradle service running that caused the error,beacuse I have a fresh set up of flutter.Thank you so much for your help